# Битые ссылки в меню

Tags: поддержка

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpcS5.jpg]

у меня в интерфейсе показывает то, что есть новый комментарий, а вот [сам комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2#comment-1104006) почему-то не доступен.

А что случилось??

Comment: Его стёрли, например.

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае было стерто твое предложение выдвинуть @NickVolynkin, и, как следствие, все комментарии под ним.

Поэтому при переходе ничего не показывается.

С другой стороны в шапке просто не обновился счетчик, и если ты обновишь страницу, то этого ответа в списке уже не должно быть.

Comment: но он есть. даже после обновления страницы: `CTRL+F5`, `CTRL+R`: [screen shot](http://joxi.ru/Rmz5lokSWJ7wLr)

Comment: @EugenKonkov это кеш. Grundy не виноват.

Comment: @alexolut: Явно где-то на стороне сервера

Comment: @EugenKonkov от этого он не перестаёт быть кешем ;)

Comment: @alexolut, еще как вариант, проблема именно со страницей выборов, тогда это вполне может быть и багом @EugenKonkov `

Comment: Ромб сказал, что не дефект :)

Comment: @alexolut, с Одедом не поспоришь :-D

Comment: Ну, можно попробовать откатить. Хехе :)